# Using \isodd in a longtable

Tags: longtable, rowcolor, isodd

I want to use something like

`\ifthenelse{\isodd{rowno}}{\rowcolor{green!30}}{\rowcolor{blue!30}}&$\mathbb{N}$ & The set of all natural numbers\\ \hline`

But it is not working. It gives me the error ! Misplaced \noalign.

In the same way if I want to color every third row green, how could I do that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl} %For coloring row, column or cell
\usepackage{longtable} %to break tables across pages
\usepackage{array} %Used for autonumbering row of a table.
\newcounter{rowno}
\setcounter{rowno}{0}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{|r<{\stepcounter{rowno}(\therowno)} | l | l |}
\hline
\rowcolor{orange}\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\small \textbf{No.}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\small Symbol} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\small Description of the set}\\
\hline
\ifthenelse{\isodd{rowno}}{\rowcolor{green!30}}{\rowcolor{blue!30}}& The set of all natural numbers\\ \hline
\rowcolor{blue!30} &$\mathbb{Z}$ & The set of all integers \\ \hline
\rowcolor{green!30} &$J_n$ & $\{1,2,3,\dots , n\}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$\\ \hline
\rowcolor{blue!30} &$\mathbb{Q}$ & The set of all rational numbers\\ \hline
\rowcolor{green!30} &$\mathbb{R}$ & The set of all real numbers\\ \hline
\rowcolor{blue!30} &$\mathbb{C}$ & The set of all complex numbers\\ \hline
\caption{Standard Sets}\label{Tab:001}
\end{longtable}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\ifthenelse` isn't expandable, so it stops TeX looking for things such as `\noalign` (which is implicitly used by `\rowcolor`)  or `\multicolumn`.

You can use the primitive test.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable} %to break tables across pages
\usepackage{array} %Used for autonumbering row of a table.
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\newcounter{rowno}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|r<{\stepcounter{rowno}(\therowno)} | l | l |}
\hline
\rowcolor{orange}
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\small \textbf{No.}} &
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\small Symbol} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\small Description of the set}\\
\hline
\ifodd\value{rowno}\rowcolor{green!30}\else\rowcolor{blue!30}\fi &
$\mathbb{N}$ & The set of all natural numbers\\ \hline
\rowcolor{blue!30} &$\mathbb{Z}$ & The set of all integers \\ \hline
\rowcolor{green!30} &$J_n$ & $\{1,2,3,\dots , n\}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$\\ \hline
\rowcolor{blue!30} &$\mathbb{Q}$ & The set of all rational numbers\\ \hline
\rowcolor{green!30} &$\mathbb{R}$ & The set of all real numbers\\ \hline
\rowcolor{blue!30} &$\mathbb{C}$ & The set of all complex numbers\\ \hline
\caption{Standard Sets}\label{Tab:001}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Note that you needn't load `colortbl`, because `xcolor` does it with the `table` option.

[image]

I'm not sure that the test is really what you want, though. Use `\rowcolors` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable} %to break tables across pages
\usepackage{array} %Used for autonumbering row of a table.
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\newcounter{rowno}

\begin{document}

\rowcolors{2}{green!30}{blue!30}
\begin{longtable}{|r<{\stepcounter{rowno}(\therowno)} | l | l |}
\hline
\rowcolor{orange}
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\small \textbf{No.}} &
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\small Symbol} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\small Description of the set}\\
\hline
&$\mathbb{N}$ & The set of all natural numbers\\ \hline
&$\mathbb{Z}$ & The set of all integers \\ \hline
&$J_n$ & $\{1,2,3,\dots , n\}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$\\ \hline
&$\mathbb{Q}$ & The set of all rational numbers\\ \hline
&$\mathbb{R}$ & The set of all real numbers\\ \hline
&$\mathbb{C}$ & The set of all complex numbers\\ \hline
\rowcolor{white}\caption{Standard Sets}\label{Tab:001} \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't see why using `longtable` here. Anyway, it should not be enclosed in `center`.

Comment: I am using longtable in my document. So, I maintained it here. Wow, the `\rowcolors` is the best solution.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I tried `\rowcolors{3}{green!30}{blue!30}{red!30}`, but it does not work.